# Xcode cannot run using the selected device when trying to build on my device SDK 4.3, iPhone 3G 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I get this message and i do believe i know where the problem is.

I realized that i have IOS 4.2.1 on my iPhone (3G) and running SDK 4.3, i would guess this is the root to the problem.

As this is an old iPhone it does not support 4.3.

Is there anything i can do if i want to test on this device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the iOS Deployment Target down to 4.2. You can find this in Project -> Edit Project Settings, Build tab, in the Deployment section.

[image]

Comment: thanks Nick, now i get "Code Sign error: Provisioning profile '03129D51-4E89-454F-8E21-9805AD1E206F' can't be found".

Comment: I also have been having this problem; I set my deployment target to 4.1 (which is on my device), but still no dice in Xcode.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the Deployment Target in the Build Settings to 4.2.